# Cannot find the 'arguments' in Navigator.pushNamed when pushing to next screen

Tags: flutter, dart, navigator

I am trying to move signup screen to OTP screen. From Signup screen I need to pass email id to OTP screen. Now, I am using below, but cannot resolve the arguments: parameter in that.

`Navigator.pushNamed(context, Routes.ROUTE_OTP,arguments:{"id": 'email'});`

Searched so many tutorials they given there to use arguments:( but my bad I can't find:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example demonstrating your requirement follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        WidgetBuilder builder;
        Map arguments = settings.arguments;

        switch (settings.name) {
          case '/':
            builder = (
              BuildContext _,
            ) =>
                SignUp();
            break;
          case '/otp':
            builder = (
              BuildContext _,
            ) =>
                Otp(id: arguments["id"]);
            break;
          default:
            return null;
        }
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: builder, settings: settings);
      },
    );
  }
}

class SignUp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Signup"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                "/otp",
                arguments: {
                  "id": "email@email.com",
                },
              );
            },
            child: Text("SEND OTP")),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Otp extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;

  Otp({this.id});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("OTP"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(id),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: gif]

Comment: Which version of flutter are you using?

Comment: version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

Comment: you can check the version using the command `flutter doctor`. It's going to be something like `Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.2, ...`

Comment: Flutter (Channel beta, v0.11.13, on Mac OS X 10.14.5 18F132)

Comment: After I upgraded my flutter works fine:) Thanks lot @10101010